# Recursively load files from directory and subdirectories with require-all

Tags: javascript, recursion, path

I have json files within a directory and subdirectory that I am wanting to match with specific criteria, however I am unaware as how to work with the subdirectories.

I am using [require-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-all) to find the json files:

```
const reqAll = require('require-all')({
  dirname: __dirname + '/resource',
  filter: /(.+)\.json$/,
  recursive: true
});
```

My file tree is as such:

```
MyDir
- file1.json
- SubDir
-- file2.json
```

Printing `reqAll` will output:

```
{ 
  file1: { 
    path: /first,
    body: ...some body
  },
  SubDir: { 
    file2: { 
      path: /second,
      body: ...some body
    } 
  } 
}
```

I was initially using the following filter to weed out my data, as I was originally not using subdirectories, but now it makes sense to.

```
let source = Object.values(reqAll).filter(r => {
    return r.path === req.url;
}
```

where `req.url` is the url of the http request I am sending in. ie: `localhost:8080/first`, so that this will match with the `file1` file I have in my directory.

The problem is that when I submit `localhost:8080/second`, I do not get a response because I cannot match to `file2` as this is within a subdir. Also sending `localhost:8080/SubDir/file2` does not work.

Is there a way in which I can get this to work?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - When I said `Printing...` I meant actually printing the variable `reqAll`. If for the filter I make it simply print there, it does just output the filenames.

Comment: Ignore me. My subdirectory was called `x` and I managed to just overlook it in the output. I get output just like yours. :-)

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you want to do with these JSON files. Are the `path` properties supposed to be paths you define for an HTTP server? (E.g., with ExpressJS or Koa or...) And then there's other data in that same object (the objects with `path` in them) that you use when handling that request?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - So, I will perform a HTTP GET on, `localhost:8080/first` and it should return me the body of the `file1` object. This does in fact work for this endpoint. However, it is when I perform a HTTP GET on `localhost:8080/second` that I cannot get the body back. It is because of the `let source...` section. It is assuming each new object begins with the filename and will have `path` attribute directly beneath, whereas we can see the second object begins with the directory name with only filename directly beneath. The `path` attribute is buried in a second layer of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you've written:

> So, I will perform a HTTP GET on, localhost:8080/first and it should return me the body of the file1 object. This does in fact work for this endpoint. However, it is when I perform a HTTP GET on localhost:8080/second that I cannot get the body back.

To do that, you'll need a recursive search for the entry with that `path`, something along these lines (see comments):

```js
const repAll = { 
    file1: { 
        path: "/first"
    },
    SubDir: { 
        file2: { 
            path: "/second"
        },
        SubSubDir: {
            file3: {
                path: "/third"
            }
        }
    } 
};
const req = {};

function findEntry(data, path) {
    for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
        // Is this a leaf node or a container?
        if (value.path) {
            // Leaf, return it if it's a match
            if (value.path === path) {
                return value;
            }
        } else {
            // Container, look inside it recursively
            const entry = findEntry(value, path);
            if (entry) {
                return entry;
            }
        }
    }
    return undefined; // Just to be explicit
}

for (const url of ["/first", "/second", "/third", "fourth"]) {
    req.url = url;
    console.log(req.url + ":", findEntry(repAll, req.url));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I added a second subdirectory to ensure the recursion keeps working, and an example of what you get back if you don't find a matching path.

You could, of course, build a map by processing `repAll` once up front and then reuse the map, which would be faster than this linear search:

```js
const repAll = { 
    file1: { 
        path: "/first"
    },
    SubDir: { 
        file2: { 
            path: "/second"
        },
        SubSubDir: {
            file3: {
                path: "/third"
            }
        }
    } 
};

const byPath = new Map();
function indexEntries(map, data) {
    for (const value of Object.values(data)) {
        if (value) {
            // Leaf or container?
            if (value.path) {
                map.set(value.path, value);
            } else {
                indexEntries(map, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
indexEntries(byPath, repAll);

const req = {};
for (const url of ["/first", "/second", "/third", "fourth"]) {
    req.url = url;
    console.log(req.url + ":", byPath.get(req.url));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I'm still a junior at the moment, so when people say 'recursion' to me I glaze over XD. But your code actually makes it seem sense to me now! Thanks for the help TJ